# C# Windwos Form datagridview Checkbox Interlocking

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, datagridview

I wrote a C# Windows Form program, the effect which I want is in the below. 
When the users click the `All` checkbox, and all the checkboxs of the row will be checked. On the other hand, if the user click the `All` checkbox again, all the checkbox of the row will be unchecked. In addition, if the user unckeck any checkbox(exclusive `All` checkbox), the `All` checkbox have to be unchecked. However, the `CellValueChanged` will be invoked when the value of the any box changed. It is difficult to handle. And, I always get infinite loop by my code. Can Anybody can fix it? Thanks a lot!!

[image]

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 1 && e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value))
            {
                //check all the Checkboxs 
                for (int i = 2; i < 26; i++)
                    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[i].Value = true;

                //if the other row all checked, unchecked it all
                for(int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (i == e.RowIndex)
                        continue;

                    if(Convert.ToBoolean(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value))
                    {
                        for(int j = 1; j < dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++)
                        {
                            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
                for (int i = 2; i < 26; i++)
                    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[i].Value = false;
        }
        else if(e.ColumnIndex > 1 && e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
                bool flag = true;
                for (int i = 2; i < dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (!Convert.ToBoolean(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[i].Value))
                        flag = false;
                }

                if (flag)
                    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value = false;
                else
                    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value = true;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem of the infinite loop is that dataGridView1_CellValueChanged call itself each time.

I suggest to add Lock(object) to dataGridView1_CellValueChanged, in this case the call that check if all the rows all check or not will not invoked until all the check boxes marked as checked.